# Alignment of floated divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've got two divs inside main container's div. First div got fixed width /160px/ and is floated to left, second div contains only button which should be aligned to the right so I set float to right.
Main div has 25% widht of the whole page width and I'm using bootstrap in my app.

Everything works fine until the widh of paret div small to fit both divs so the right one is moved under the left one - but is there some way how to align /center/ second div in this situaton? So where both divs are alone in the row, they should be aligned to center of parent, but when they are in the same row, first one should be aligned to left and second one to right or maybe to center of availible space /parent div widh minus 160px of the first div/.

Many thanks for any advice,
Peter

EDIT:
container style: `width:25%;`

first /left/ div style: `float:left; widht:160px;`

second /right/ div style: `margin-top:5px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example demonstrating how to do it.

```css
#container
{
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#left
{
  width: 160px;
  height: 5em;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}
#right
{
  float: right;
  height: 5em;
  background: blue;
}
@media (max-width: 872px)
{
  #right
  {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='left'>
  
  </div>
  <div id='right'>
    <button>
      Button
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should use a `@media` query, with a breakpoint set to a viewport size where the two divs can't fit on the same line.
Then in that media query set the right div to

```
float: none;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
```

**HINT**: View the code-snippet results full-paged, and then resize your window to see the effects.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: No, you've edited your question. I've edited my answer.